# What does the slice() function do in Python? (compared to slice notation)

Tags: python, function, slice

I wanted to comment on the accepted answer on [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501806/what-does-the-slice-function-do-in-python) of the same name but I'm way too green.

That answer, "a[x:y:z] is gives the same result as a[slice(x, y, z)]", is not proving true in my attempts so I am seeking a deeper understanding of the differences between slice() and the slice notation.

I have a serial protocol that has a message body like this: Q0134CA24B.

If I want to collect elements of that protocol, it would be very nice to do this:

```
>>> str = 'Q0134CA24B'
>>> cmd = slice(0,1)
>>> str[cmd]
'Q'
>>> cs = slice(-2,0)
>>> str[cs]
''
>>> cs
slice(-2, 0, None)
>>> str[cs]
''
>>> str[-2:None:None]
'4B'
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Is slice() just limited compared to slice notation?  This would be very useful to me since I am frequently working in serial protocols and defining character fields with slice() would be a pythonic way to pass this representation around.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem.  The statement "a[x:y:z] is gives the same result as a[slice(x, y, z)]", is not proving true in my attempts" -- I don't see any attempts where you demonstrate an inconsistency between these two...

Comment: None of your tests display a difference between `a[x:y:z]` and `a[slice(x, y, z)]`.

Comment: Jeez that dupe has the exact same title too... it's almost like you can google it.

Comment: Why are you expecting `slice(-2, 0)` to act like `[-2:]`?  `[-2:]` is equivalent to `slice(-2, None)`

Comment: @SterlingArcher: The questioner actually *did* find that post. It's linked in the first line of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to correct "stop".

The two notations are consistent, maybe you are confusing `0` with `None`?  `0` is a position, `None` is the absence of that.  To quote the source code (`Objects/sliceobject.c`): "*start, stop, and step are python objects with None indicating no index is present.*"

`None` and `0` are the same for a start position.

```
>>> s = 'Q0134CA24B'
>>> s[:1]
'Q'
>>> s[0:1]
'Q'
```

For stop, `None` means "through to the end of the sequence", whereas `0` means a position.

```
>>> s = 'Q0134CA24B'
>>> s[1:]
'0134CA24B'
>>> s[1:0]
''

>>> s[::-1]    # Simple 'reverse' trick
'B42AC4310Q'
>>> s[:None:-1]
'B42AC4310Q'
>>> s[:0:-1]
'B42AC4310'
```

For step, `None` means one, but `0` is invalid and will raise a `ValueError`, and that is the same if you are using `[ ]` notation or `slice()`.

Taking your examples (`str` is a bad name for a variable):

```
>>> s = 'Q0134CA24B'
>>> cmd = slice(0,1)
>>> s[cmd]
'Q'
>>> s[0:1]
'Q'

>>> cs = slice(-2,0)
>>> s[cs]
''
>>> s[-2:0]
''
>>> cs
slice(-2, 0, None)

>>> s[-2:None:None]
'4B'
>>> s[-2::]
'4B'
>>> cd = slice(-2,None,None)
>>> str[cd]
'4B'
```

There is no inconsistency there.

Comment: Many thanks for the root cause of my misunderstanding in the first line and for the kind explanation.  But I feel really stupid for the error.

Comment: "For length ..." - no, there's no length parameter. You're getting stop and length mixed up. A stop value of 0 means the subsequence you're selecting ends at index 0 of the original sequence (exclusive), not that you're selecting a subsequence of length 0.

Comment: @user2357112: oops - you are correct - edited