# How to select second level in multiindex when using columns?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe with this index:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['stock1','stock2'...],['price','volume'...]])
```

It's a useful structure for being able to do `df['stock1']`, but how do I select all the price data? I can't make any sense of the documentation.

I've tried the following with no luck: `df[:,'price']` `df[:]['price']` `df.loc(axis=1)[:,'close']` `df['price]`

If this index style is generally agreed to be a bad idea for whatever reason, then what would be a better choice? Should I go for a multi-indexed index for the stocks as labels on the time series instead of at the column level?

EDIT - I am using the multiindex for the columns, not the index (the wording got the better of me). The examples in the documentation focus on multi-level indexes rather than column structures.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index

Comment: If you are interested in learning more about slicing and filtering multiindex DataFrames, please take a look at my post: [How do I slice or filter MultiIndex DataFrame levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/how-do-i-slice-or-filter-multiindex-dataframe-levels).

Comment: `df.loc(axis=1)[:,'price']` works fine for me in pandas 1.5; perhaps it was enhanced more recently.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Also using John's data sample:

Using `xs()` is another way to slice a `MultiIndex`:

```
df
               0
stock1 price   1
       volume  2
stock2 price   3
       volume  4
stock3 price   5
       volume  6

df.xs('price', level=1, drop_level=False)
              0
stock1 price  1
stock2 price  3
stock3 price  5
```

Alternatively if you have a `MultiIndex` in place of columns:

```
df
  stock1        stock2        stock3       
   price volume  price volume  price volume
0      1      2      3      4      5      6

df.xs('price', axis=1, level=1, drop_level=False)
  stock1 stock2 stock3
   price  price  price
0      1      3      5
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. as a result of my being new to Multiindexing my question was poorly written.
I was using the multiindex for the columns, not the index.

`df.xs('price',axis=1,level=1)` does the job perfectly

Comment: Just here to say that .xs is still in use in pandas 1.1.3: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

Answer (score 61):

Using [@JohnZwinck's data sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45128603/5741205):

```
In [132]: df
Out[132]:
               0
stock1 price   1
       volume  2
stock2 price   3
       volume  4
stock3 price   5
       volume  6
```

**Option 1:**

```
In [133]: df.loc[(slice(None), slice('price')), :]
Out[133]:
              0
stock1 price  1
stock2 price  3
stock3 price  5
```

**Option 2:**

```
In [134]: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'price'], :]
Out[134]:
              0
stock1 price  1
stock2 price  3
stock3 price  5
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> But what if for the 2nd Index, I want to select everything but price
> and there are multiple values so that enumeration is not an option. Is
> there something like slice(~'price')

first let's name the index levels:

```
df = df.rename_axis(["lvl0", "lvl1"])
```

now we can use the `df.query()` method:

```
In [18]: df.query("lvl1 != 'price'")
Out[18]:
               0
lvl0   lvl1
stock1 volume  2
stock2 volume  4
stock3 volume  6
```

Comment: Works, but what is the `slice()` function doing? The python website wasn't helpful for me. Said slice() returns indices. Can I do something like list(slice(...))? Apparently not.

Comment: @muuh, please check [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501806/what-does-the-slice-function-do-in-python) - I hope that helps...

Comment: For Option 1, this also works: `df.loc[(slice(None),'price'), :]`. In other words, to select a specific value for that index level, just use the value.

Comment: Great answer. But what if for the 2nd Index, I want to select everything but `price` and there are multiple values so that enumeration is not an option. Is there something like `slice(~'price')`

Comment: In `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'price'], :]` what does the last : mean? Also, apparently you can do `df.loc[:, 'price', :]`...

Comment: @loco.loop, the last “:” explicitly  instructs pandas to select all columns. Are you sure that your version would do the thing? Did you test it?

Comment: Using the 1st option, `slice`, I get a "too many indexers" error (on a dataframe with multi-index of 2 levels). Any idea?

Answer (score 17):

I have found the most intuitive solution for accessing a second-level column in a DataFrame with MultiIndex columns is using `.loc` together with `slice()`.

In case of your DataFrame with

```py
df
  stock1        stock2        stock3       
   price volume  price volume  price volume
0      1      2      3      4      5      6
1      2      3      4      5      6      7
```

using `df.loc[:, (slice(None), "price")]`

would deliver all columns with the sub-column of `"price"`

```py
  stock1  stock2  stock3       
   price   price   price 
0      1       3       5
1      2       4       6
```

Within `df.loc[:, (slice(None), "price")]` the first argument of loc `:` delivers the result for all rows, the second argument `(slice(None), "price")` is a tuple responsible for selecting all first level columns (`slice(None)`) and all second-level columns with the name of `"price"`.

Answer (score 9):

`df.unstack()` will "tear off" the last level of your `MultiIndex` and make your DataFrame a lot more conventional, with one column per type of data.  For example:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['stock1','stock2','stock3'],['price','volume']])
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6], index)
print(df.unstack())
```

Gives you:

```
           0       
       price volume
stock1     1      2
stock2     3      4
stock3     5      6
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also swap levels first, then select by the first level (based on @ntg's [sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72907992/3025981)):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': range(6),
    'stocks': [f'stock{i // 2}' for i in range(6)],
    'attr': ['price', 'volume'] * 3
}).set_index(['stocks', 'attr'])

df.swaplevel().loc["price"]

        value
stocks       
stock0      0
stock1      2
stock2      4
```

Works on columns with `axis=1` as well.

Answer (score 1):

While @MaxU's is the better answer, I want to point out here that we can also separately reset_index any part of a MultiIndex, e.g., suppose:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'price':range(6),
    'stocks': [f'stock{i//2}' for i in range(6)],
    'attr':['price','volume']*3
}).set_index(['stocks','attr'])
```

leading to df:

```
               price
stocks attr         
stock0 price       0
       volume      1
stock1 price       2
       volume      3
stock2 price       4
       volume      5
```

Then e.g.:

```
df_rst = df.reset_index('attr')
df_rst[df_rst['attr']=='price']
```

will lead to:
[image]

Answer (score -5):

I also noticed you missed this option:

```
df.loc[:,"price"]
```

As far as a best practice for your time data, keep it in a column corresponding to rows, preferably as a datetime object in Python (pandas has built in feature support for it). You can use the mask syntax to only get times relevant to your interest.

That is how you access a single column of your data frame. However for multiple columns we can pass a list, or a colon to get all:

```
df.loc[:,["price","volume"]] 
#or
df.loc[:,:]
```

A useful way to query (and quickly) is to use masks to specify which rows/columns meet what condition you want:

```
Mask=df.loc[:,"price"]>50.0
df.loc[Mask, "stock"] #should return the stock prices greater than 50bucks.
```

Hope this helps, and as always feel free to follow up on this answer if I completely misunderstood your question, I'd love to help further.

Comment: are you using  data frame?

Comment: Yes, look at my answer here for the precise DataFrame I am using.