# Is it possible to unpack values from list to slice?

Tags: python, slice, unpack

I'm trying to use values in list to select part of word. Here is working solution:

```
word = 'abc'*4
slice = [2,5]  #it can contain 1-3 elements

def try_catch(list, index):
    try:
        return list[index]
    except IndexError:
        return None

print(word[slice[0]:try_catch(slice,1):try_catch(slice,2)])
```

but I wonder if is it possible to shorten it? Something like this comes to my mind:

```
word = 'abc'*4
slice = [2,6,2]
print(word[':'.join([str(x) for x in slice])]) #missing : for one element in list
```

It produces:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: Don't name your variable `slice` as that overwrites `__builtin__.slice`. You may be looking for `word[slice(*[2,6,2])]` (using the builtin function here, not your variable) but it's hard to tell without the desired output. Read more here [What does the slice() function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501806/what-does-the-slice-function-do-in-python).

Comment: So you want to build the following slice `2:6:2`?

Comment: Your "working solution" errors out with a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: `word[start:stop:step]` in case of `slice = [2,6,2]` it would be `word[2:6:2]` so just `cb`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the slice() function do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501806/what-does-the-slice-function-do-in-python)

Comment: Yes, this link is exactly what I needed. Thanks. Also fixed `SyntaxError` in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) (and need to name your list differently to be able to access the built-in):

```
>>> word = 'abcdefghijk'
>>> theslice = [2, 10, 3]
>>> word[slice(*theslice)]
'cfi'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a python `[slice][1]`, but causes a syntax error, because `[..]` syntax for getting a slice, not creating it:

```
slice = [2:5]
Out:
...
SyntaxError
```

`slice` is a python builtin, so don't shadow it's name. Create slice as

```
my_slice = slice(2, 5, 1)
```

where first argument is a start value, next is a stop value and the last is the step size:

```
my_list = list(range(10))
my_list
Out:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

my_list[my_slice]
Out:
[2, 3, 4]

my_list[slice(3, 8, 2)]
Out:
[2, 4, 6]
```

Note that we should use `[]` with a slice, as it calls a [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method of a list which accepts a `slice` objects (look last link for the `__getitem__` and `slice`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
word = 'abc'*4
w = list(word)
s = slice(2,6,2)
print("".join(w[s]))
```