# How to unpack a tuple when indexing?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very high dimensional tensor, say A with shape 5 X 10 X 100 X 200 X 50.
I have a some numpy expression that returns a tuple T, containing indices of elements that I want to extract from A.

I'm trying this:

```
A[*T]
```

It says:

> invalid syntax, you cannot use starred expressions here.

How can I do it?
PS: The long solution is: A[T[0], T[1], T[2], T[3], T[4]]

EDIT: I just found that there is no need to do that as it is being done automatically. Example:

```
a= np.random.rand(3,3)
a[np.triu_indices(3)]
```

The expression `np.triu_indices(3)` is being unpacked automatically when passed to `a` as index. **However**, going back to my question it is not happening. To be concrete, here's an example:

```
a = np.random.rand(100, 50, 14, 14)
a[:, :, np.triu_indices(14)].shape
```

Supposedly, the last bit `np.triu_indices(14)` should act on last two axes, as in the previous example, but it is not happening, and the shape resulting is weird. Why isn't being unpacked? and how to do that?

Comment: Doesn't `A[T]` or `A[tuple(T)]` work?

Comment: T is already a tuple, so taking tuple of tuple won't help. A[T] works for 2D matrix, but for high order tensor it behaves weirdly.

Comment: It works independently of dimensionality. Maybe what you observe is related to combining advanced and basic indexing https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing ?

Comment: @norok2 Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing. Along the first two axes, I'm using slicing, and along the last two, I'm passing indcies.

Comment: and what shape do you expect from the output?

Comment: Good question. As for the concrete example I gave above, it should be (100, 50, 105) Which I got indeed when explicitly doing this a[:, :, np.triu_indices(14)[0], np.triu_indices(14)[1]]

Comment: Python 3 has added a lot of power to the * unpacking, but it is not allowed in an indexing expression - at least not directly.  `a[1,2,*(3,4)]` raises a **syntax error**.  `a[(1,2,*(3,4)]` expands to `a[(1,2,3,4)]` or equivalently `a[1,2,3,4])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with:

```
a[:, :, np.triu_indices(14)]
```

is that you are using as argument for `[]` a tuple of mixed types `slice` and `tuple` (`tuple(slice, slice, tuple(np.ndarray, np.ndarray))`) and not a single `tuple` (eventually with advanced indexing), e.g. `tuple(slice, slice, np.ndarray, np.ndarray)`.
This is causing your troubles. I would not go into the details of what is happening in your case.

Changing that line to:

```py
a[(slice(None),) * 2 + np.triu_indices(14)]
```

will fix your issues:

```py
a[(slice(None),) * 2 + np.triu_indices(14)].shape
# (100, 50, 105)
```

---

Note that there are a couple of ways for rewriting:

```py
(slice(None),) * 2 + np.triu_indices(14)
```

another way may be:

```py
(slice(None), slice(None), *np.triu_indices(14))
```

---

Also, if you want to use the `...` syntax, you need to know that `...` is syntactic sugar for `Ellipsis`, so that:

```py
(Ellipsis,) + np.triu_indices(14)
```

or:

```py
(Ellipsis, *np.triu_indices(14))
```

would work correctly:

```py
a[(Ellipsis,) + np.triu_indices(14)].shape                                                   
# (100, 50, 105)
a[(Ellipsis, *np.triu_indices(14))].shape                                                   
# (100, 50, 105)
```

Comment: I didn't get it, sorry. What is even slice? is that a keyword? and what is [...] ? I think my expression is perfectly legitimate a[:, :, np.triu_indices(14)] ? Please elaborate the answer in layman's terms.

Comment: Basically, `:` is syntactic sugar for: `slice(None)`, see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501806/what-does-the-slice-function-do-in-python for more info.

Comment: That is genuis. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, you said "I wouldn't go into details of what's happening". It is actually quite simple. The tuple is thought of as: I want this axis to be sliced in two ways. That's why in the result, an extra dimension showed up. (100, 50, 2, 105, 14) Number 2! While the last dimension (14) remained intact cause we didn't pass anything about it. This is insightful, and tells that you can slice one axis in mutiple ways in a one-liner!

Comment: What if you want to do something like: a[..., np.triu_indices(14)]? Your solution requires you to know the number of slices a priori.

Comment: @Seanslice My solution has the same requirements as the original question. If you want to have the flexibility provided by `...` you have to use `Ellipsis`, but the underlying observation of combining the tuples as flattened still holds.