# How to assign to a numpy slice view obtained from unpacking triu_indices

Tags: python, numpy

I'm attempting to assign values to a slice of a 4-tensor based on indices obtained with triu_indices.  However, I am only able to assign values to the slice view, rather than the underlying data.

I used this article

[How to unpack a tuple when indexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57038428/how-to-unpack-a-tuple-when-indexing/57038776)

to obtain a 6x6 slice of a 4x4x4x4 tensor.  I have seen plenty of articles where it's possible to assign data to array slices, but I'm unclear why my syntax isn't working for this purpose.

```
import numpy as np
t_vec = np.ones(6,6)
n_occs = 4
n_nnoccs = 4
t2 = np.zeros((n_noccs, n_noccs, n_occs, n_occs)).astype(np.float)
O = (np.triu_indices(n_occs, 1)) 
t2[O][(slice(None),) + V] = t_vec
t2[V][(slice(None),) + O] = t_vec
```

Expected results are to replace 72 of the 256 entries of t2 with ones.  Actual output is the original 0 matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing with the `triu_indices` produces a copy; those indices are produced by a `where` function, and perform advanced indexing:

```
In [40]: x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)                                                                       
In [41]: idx = np.triu_indices(3)                                                                            
In [42]: idx                                                                                                 
Out[42]: (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2]))
In [43]: x[idx]                                                                                              
Out[43]: array([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8])
```

Note that `Out[43]` is a 1d array - selected values from `x`.

We can assign directly to it, either with a scalar or a compatible array (1d):

```
In [44]: x[idx] = 0                                                                                          
In [45]: x                                                                                                   
Out[45]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0],
       [6, 7, 0]])
In [46]: x[idx] = np.arange(1,7)                                                                             
In [47]: x                                                                                                   
Out[47]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 6]])
```

But we cannot add another layer of indexing.

In your 4d case:

```
In [56]: t2 = np.arange(4**4).reshape(4,4,4,4)
```

`t2[idx]` produces a (6,4,4) array, a copy.  The next layer of indexing produces a (6,6):

```
In [57]: t2[idx][:,idx[0],idx[1]]                                                                            
Out[57]: 
array([[ 17,  18,  19,  22,  23,  27],
       [ 33,  34,  35,  38,  39,  43],
       [ 49,  50,  51,  54,  55,  59],
       [ 97,  98,  99, 102, 103, 107],
       [113, 114, 115, 118, 119, 123],
       [177, 178, 179, 182, 183, 187]])
```

If I apply the 2 elements of `idx` twice, I get the diagonal of that (6,6):

```
In [58]: t2[idx[0],idx[1],idx[0],idx[1]]                                                                     
Out[58]: array([ 17,  34,  51, 102, 119, 187])
```

I can do the 4d indexing in one step with:

```
In [59]: t2[idx[0][:,None],idx[1][:,None],idx[0],idx[1]]                                                     
Out[59]: 
array([[ 17,  18,  19,  22,  23,  27],
       [ 33,  34,  35,  38,  39,  43],
       [ 49,  50,  51,  54,  55,  59],
       [ 97,  98,  99, 102, 103, 107],
       [113, 114, 115, 118, 119, 123],
       [177, 178, 179, 182, 183, 187]])
```

I could assign values to that, and modify `t2`.

```
In [60]: t2[idx[0][:,None],idx[1][:,None],idx[0],idx[1]]=0                                                   
In [61]: t2                                                                                                  
Out[61]: 
array([[[[  0,   1,   2,   3],
         [  4,   5,   6,   7],
         [  8,   9,  10,  11],
         [ 12,  13,  14,  15]],

        [[ 16,   0,   0,   0],
         [ 20,  21,   0,   0],
         [ 24,  25,  26,   0],
         [ 28,  29,  30,  31]],
    ....
```

Comment: I'm confused by what the [idx[0][:,None], idx[1][:,None]] does as opposed to [idx].  What does [:,None] do in general?

Comment: It adds a dimension.  It changes the `idx[0]` array, with shape (6,) into a 'column vector' with shape (6,1).  You many need to read up on broadcasting and 'advanced indexing'.